# Detect when a JTable in a JScrollPane is scrolled close to the bottom

Tags: java, swing

Given

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(table);
```

I want to detect when the table is scrolled close to the bottom (so new rows can be loaded and added). Is there a difference for this purpose between `scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener()` and `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener()`?

Comment: as your description lets me assume, you don't load all the data into the table at once. why would you do that?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Because loading the data takes time and the user should be able to access initial data without having to wait until all data is available. E.g. all data is for many decades, but users mostly care about last few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener()
```

will trigger only on vertical scroll activity.

```
scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener()
```

will trigger on changes to properties of the viewport, changes on scroll position, and changes to the viewport container.

Functionally for your purpose, both should work.

Answer (score 4):

Hook up an adjustment listener to the vertical scroll bar and fetch data when user scrolls to the end of the view

```
final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
//Hook up listener to vertical scroll bar
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener(){ 
    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        // Check if user has done dragging the scroll bar
        if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
            JScrollBar scrollBar = (JScrollBar) e.getAdjustable();
            int extent = scrollBar.getModel().getExtent();
            int maximum = scrollBar.getModel().getMaximum();
            if(extent + e.getValue() == maximum){
                fetchMoreData();
            }
        }

    }
});
```